# Как правильно должен выглядеть Model в MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Возьмем простое View, в котором есть два TextBox и Button

```
 <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxOne}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxTwo}"/>
        <Button Content="Рассчитать" Command="{Binding CalculateCommand}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

Задача: найти сумму чисел, введенных в TextBox.

```
 public class Model
    {
        public string TextBoxOne { get; set; }
        public string TextBoxTwo { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }

    }
```

```
 private RelayCommand calculateCommand;
 Model model = new Model();

        public string TextBoxOne
        {
            get => model.TextBoxOne;
            set
            {
                model.TextBoxOne= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxOne");
            }
        }

        public string TextBoxTwo
        {
            get => model.TextBoxTwo;
            set
            {
                model.TextBoxTwo= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxTwo");
            }
        }

        public string Result
        {
            get => model.Result;
            set
            {
                model.Result= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }

private string Calculating(string one, string two)
{
   string result = Convert.ToDouble(one) + Convert.ToDouble(two);
   return result;
}

  public RelayCommand CalculateCommand=> calculateCommand??  "Разрядность"
                    (calculateCommand= new RelayCommand((o) =>
                    {

                       Result = Calculating(TextBoxOne, TextBoxTwo);
                    }
                    }));
```

Вопрос в том, правильно ли я использую MVVM, нужно ли создавать интерфейс для модели, стоит ли переменным в ViewModel обращаться каждый раз к Model или лучше писать методы в Model? А также стоит ли каждый расчет (если их много на одной View будет) выносить по методам, чтобы потом писать к ним Unit тесты?

Comment: "стоит ли каждый расчет ... выносить" -- хуже вроде не будет. Кода почти столько же, а гибкость больше. Тоже с интерфейсом. Я правда не любил интерфейсы из-за того, что они занимают место в области видимости директории, но можно реализацию вынести в отдельную поддиректорию (Impl), если классов в директории станет слишком много.

Comment: Имхо, в такой простой задаче модель вообще не нужна. ну и я не сторонник подхода, при котором вы делаете свойства VM лишь обертками над свойствами модели, как по мне — лучше делать полноценные свойства, а вот при нажатии кнопки Применить/ОК/и т. п. мы создаем или изменяем уже непосредственно модельные классы и сохраняем их или передаем на сервер или что там вам еще нужно. Но да, всё зависит от задачи и в конкретной ситуации может быть удобен тот или иной вариант решения.